# how to convert received datetime object to timestamp in php?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I receive from POST the datetime object (eg. `30/06/2015 02:04 PM`). I need to use it later in my php code as a timestamp, so the variable `$begin_timestamp = $_POST['date'];` would contain a timestamp instead of this date time. How can I quickly change it at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the static method of `createFromFormat()` of the `DateTime` class:

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A', '30/06/2015 02:04 PM');
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp(); // 1435665840
?>
```

Comment: thanks, I'm just starting with php, so could you tell me if I can use it as follows:

`$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A', $_POST['date']);
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();` ?

Comment: @randomuser1: watch out for format H, if you are using am and pm you will probably have 12-hour format... In that case use lowercase h as format